# insert column to df on sequenced location

Tags: pandas, dataframe, join, pandas-groupby, transform

i have a df like this:

| id | month |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 3 |
| 1 | 4 |
| 1 | 6 |

i want to transform it become like this:

| id | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 |

ive tried using this code:

```
ndf = df[['id']].join(pd.get_dummies(
    df['month'])).groupby('id').max()
```

but it shows like this:

| id | 1 | 3 | 4 | 6 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |

how can i insert the middle column (2 and 5) even if it's not in the data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`pd.crosstab`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html)
instead, then create new columns using [`pd.RangeIndex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.RangeIndex.html) based on the min and max `month`, and finally use [`DataFrame.reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) (and optionally [`DataFrame.reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) afterwards):

```
import pandas as pd

new_cols = pd.RangeIndex(df['month'].min(), df['month'].max())

res = (
    pd.crosstab(df['id'], df['month'])
     .reindex(columns=new_cols, fill_value=0)
     .reset_index()
)
```

Output:

```
>>> res

   id  1  2  3  4  5
0   1  1  0  1  1  0
```